# Casting Object (which is of type Map<String, String>) to Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java

I have an `Object` which is of type `Map<String, String>` which has few entries. I expected to get a `ClassCastException` while casting this object to `Map<String, Integer>`. But the cast was successful. Why is it that this did not throw any exception?

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1", "value1");
map1.put("key2", "value2");
Object o = map1;
Map<String, Integer> map2 = (Map<String, Integer>) o;
```

Edit: Casting from `o` not `map1`.

Comment: The generic type parameters are only used for compile-time checking, and your casting bypasses those checks. (Though maybe you're getting compiler warnings?) The generics are lost at run-time. It won't error until you actually try and get an `Integer` from your map.

Comment: Yeah I did get the compiler warnings.
But when I tried `System.out.println(map2.get("key1"));`, it did not throw any error.

Comment: That's because `System.out.println(map2.get("key1"))` doesn't require that `get("key")` returns an `Integer`. But `Integer n = map2.get("key")`, for instance, would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Generic-checking is made at compile time,while casting checking is done at the time of running the program.So You had got casting exception at run time.

You parse it as Integer.parseInt(String) and put the value into map2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's right?
 Your example fails to compile:

```
Error:(21, 60) java: incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>
```

However, changing from map1 to o, does compile:

```
//...    
Object o = map1;
Map<String, Integer> map2 = (Map<String, Integer>) o;
```

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1", "1");
map1.put("key2", "2");
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.forEach((key,value) -> map2.put(key, Integer.parseInt(value)));
```

Comment: There was a typo. I was trying to cast `o` to `map2`, which worked perfectly fine. But I was expecting a ClassCastException there.